# Make List easier with For-Loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

datpackage <- paste0("dat",1:10)

for(i in 1:10){

  assign(datpackage[i], runif(2))

}
```

```
datlist <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6, dat7, dat8, dat9, dat10)
```

#### "datlist" is what I want, but is there easier way to make a list ?

```
datlist2 <- for (i in 1:10) {
                list(paste0("dat",i))
}

datlist3 <- list(datpackage)
```

I've tried datlist2, and datlist3, but that's not the same as "datlist".

What should I have to do when I make a list with thousands of data?

Comment: `datlist <- lapply(1:10, function(ign) runif(2))`? You can assign names afterward if needed.

Comment: @akrun's use of `replicate` is more readable code, which is typically a good thing. The use of `lapply` will be more appropriate if this is a simplified example and you need to do more for each of the 10 "things". (And since `replicate` is simply calling `sapply`, it has similar performance. Its use is mostly about personal preference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `mget` if the objects are already created

```
datlist <- mget(paste0("dat", 1:10))
```

---

But, if we need to create a list of random uniform numbers,

```
datlist <- replicate(10, runif(2), simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating lists with random numbers I would also suggest:

```
datlist2 <- lapply(vector("list", 10), function(x) {runif(2)})
```

## Benchmarking

May be worth adding that the `lapply` / `vector` approach appears to be faster:

```
funA <- function(x) {replicate(10, runif(2), simplify = FALSE)}
funB <- function(x) {lapply(vector("list", 10), function(x) {runif(2)})}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(funA(), funB(), times = 1e4)
```

### Results

```
Unit: microseconds
   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval cld
 funA() 24.053 27.3305 37.98530 28.6665 34.4045 2478.510 10000   b
 funB() 19.507 21.6400 30.37437 22.9235 27.0500 2547.145 10000  a
```

[image: Comparison - funA / funB]